# how can I add plugin using cordova?

Tags: android, cordova-3

Can someone please guide me to add a pluggin in cordova?
I wasnt able to get a proper example for plugin

plugman --platform  --project  --plugin  [--plugins_dir ] [--www ] [--variable = [--variable = ...]]

any example will be really helpful
Thanks a bunch

Answer (score 1):

Did you take some time to read the documentation?
This question has been answered several times, I am not sure why are you using plugman instead of the cordova CLI.

Here an example to install the file plugin

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.file
```

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/cordova_file_file.md.html#File

Check the API doc and all have the cordova CLI to add the plugins as required

Be sure to use the CLI also to create and build your project
cordova create ...
cordova build

If you haven't do so, go ahead and create a project from scratch to avoid problems and just copy and paste your current code in the www folder.

READ the CLI doc
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-line%20Interface